# Customized newsletters

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I've signed up for three different newsletters from Stack Exchange, each is received on an unique weekday. I learn a lot from other people's problems. The newsletters are far from the only emails I get, though, so plenty of time is spent in the inbox.

This would certainly be worth it if I found everything in the newsletters interesting, but there's often topics that are no use for me, like questions about Windows when I'm actually using Linux.

To minimize my (and others) time in the inbox I'd suggest:

1. Combined newsletters (only the ones of choice, of course)
2. Tag filters
3. Reputation filters (sometimes the most popular questions aren't necessarily popular)

Good/bad idea? :-)

Comment: With the reputation filter I mean only including questions in my newsletter with more than e.g. 20 in reputation. This question would obviously be excluded. :-)

Comment: I think I understand. You want one newsletter, where you can tweak tags that are included on a per site basis, and also "only send me questions with a score of X or higher" _also_ on a per site basis? Just confirming before I send this over to MSO - as this is different enough from the one I linked to not be a duplicate.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you. :-)

Comment: Tag filters is interesting, but I for one wouldn't want a single newsletter with all the content.  I *want* to handle my cooking news separately from my writing news separately from my programming news, etc.

Comment: +1 for #2 - I don't care about the others.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think this is a good idea. In fact I was about to open a question specifically for tag filters, as it's useless to present in the newsletter a "Can you answer these" if they are about languages I don't know.

I really support a more customized newsletter, especially with regards to filtering. It would be neat to allow customized filtering per section (e.g.: I'm ok with receiving "Greatest hits" in languages I don't usually care about, there's always something to be learned, on the other hand I'd like to filter the "Can you answer these" section, because it usually contains questions that I can't answer).

I think filtering will also help increase the number of answered question

Answer (score 0):

Actually, without tag filters the newsletters may be worthless.

For my first received newsletter, 10 of 11 items were tagged with subjects I have placed among my ignored tags.

If they're not actually filtered out, maybe they could be grayed out so at least I would feel like I'm not being ignored.